# Display 2 dropdown lists next to each other

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down ol next to each other, but when the first one is clicked, it brings the second one down with it instead of leaving it at the top.

I can't use `position: absolute` with either of them as there will be content at the bottom that needs to be pushed down when the drop down is active.

This is the code I have

HTML

```
<div id="lists">
 <div id="list_one">
 <a>List One</a>
  <ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div id="list_two">
 <a>List Two</a>
  <ol>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
     <li>Item 4</li>
     <li>Item 5</li>
     <li>Item 6</li>
     <li>Item 7</li>
     <li>Item 8</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#lists {
 border: 2px solid blue;
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
}

#list_one {
 width: 100px;
 border: 2px solid red;
}

#list_one ol {
 display: none;
}

#list_two {
 width: 100px;
 border: 2px solid green;
 position: relative;
 top: -25px;
 left: 200px;
}

#list_two ol {
 display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#list_one a').click(function(){
 $('#list_one ol').toggle();
});

$('#list_two a').click(function(){
 $('#list_two ol').toggle();
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3tctuzp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float the two lists left and right within the container, and then set the display of the container to inline-block.

So the CSS for the lists would be:

```
#lists {
 border: 2px solid blue;
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 display:inline-block
}

#list_one {
 width: 100px;
 border: 2px solid red;
 float:left;
}

#list_two {
 width: 100px;
 border: 2px solid green;
 position: relative;
 float:right;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvf5n4hf/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the list positions as relative, you could make them float. For that to work you need to set `overflow: auto` in your #lists, though. You can then float list one to the left and list two to the right. It would look something like this:

```
#list_one {   
  ...   
  float: left; 
}

#list_two {
  ...
  float: right; 
}
#lists {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is your edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3tctuzp/2/